# Permissions for /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

Tags: permissions, ssmtp

I'm just starting with my own Virtual Server (and Linux). I've an apache2 and a few WordPress sites. I need to send mails via PHP (contact forms). I managed to install ssmtp with the help of a few tutorials. It sends mail with an gmail account. I'm not sure about the right permissions of the ssmtp.conf:

When I `chmod 600 /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` I cant't send mails from the commandline, php-contact forms are also not working.

When I `chmod 640 /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` I can send mails from the commandline, but php-contact forms are not working.

When I `chmod 666 /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` I can't send mails from the commandline and php-contact forms are working fine.

Obviously I would like to stay with 666, but I'm not sure if this could be a security problem.

Comment: have you tried 644 ? (allow anyone to read)

Comment: gksudo gedit /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you have your Gmail password in the configuration file so you would want the the third number to be 0 (No permissions to Others). Ideal is `640`. You can change the ownership of the configuration file (using the command `chown`) e.g. `chown root:mail /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`.

You can send from the command line using `sudo` or as root. Your web server user also need to be a member of group `mail`. Or you can change that to `root:www-data` if the user group of the web server is `www-data`.

Comment: It's working fine with 640 after changing the ownership to root:www-data. Thank's for your help!